# What happens to loyalty counters on a double faced Planeswalker?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-double-faced-cards, mtg-planeswalkers

When a double faced planeswalker, like Garruk Relentless transforms into Garruk, the Veil Cursed there is no new loyalty symbol at the bottom of the card.

[image: Garruk Relentless]

Does his current loyalty carry over or is there some new mechanic to deal with DFC Planeswalkers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is covered by the [*Magic* Comprehensive Rules](http://www.wizards.com/Magic/TCG/Article.aspx?x=magic/rules):

> 121.1. A counter is a marker placed on an object or player that modifies its characteristics and/or 
>   interacts with a rule, ability, or effect.

---

> 711.7. When a double-faced permanent transforms, it doesn‘t become a new object. Any effects that 
>   applied to that permanent will continue to apply to it after it transforms.
>
> ***Example:** An effect gives Village Ironsmith (the front face of a double-faced card) +2/+2 
>   until end of turn and then Village Ironsmith transforms into Ironfang. Ironfang will continue 
>   to get +2/+2 until end of turn.*

When Garruk Relentless transforms into Garruk, the Veil-Cursed, he remains the same object, so there's no reason to believe anything happens to his loyalty counters.

The official [*Innistrad* FAQ](http://www.wizards.com/magic/magazine/article.aspx?x=mtg/faq/isd) mentions this as well:

> - Transforming a permanent doesn't affect any Auras or Equipment attached to that permanent. Similarly, any counters on the permanent will remain on that permanent after it transforms.

Answer (score 7):

From the official Wizards site's [article about Double-Faced Card Rules](http://www.wizards.com/magic/magazine/article.aspx?x=mtg/daily/feature/157b):

> After a double-faced card transforms, it's still the same card, so any
>   Auras, counters, or other effects stay right where they are (unless
>   the double-faced card's characteristics have changed such that an Aura
>   can no longer legally enchant it).

This obviously includes a planeswalker's loyalty counters.  I think it's helpful to imagine the "transform" action as being a literal transform - the face of the card almost magically instantaneously changes from one aspect to another.  If you think of it over-literally as "flipping the card over" then it's logical to imagine everything falling off!  But this isn't what happens.

Answer (score 6):

According to [DCI Level 2 Judge "Natedogg"](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75842/28285251/Innistrad_FAQ?post_id=506930013#506930013) the loyalty counters from the front face transfer to the back face.

Specifically

> You don't add or remove loyalty counters from Garruk Relentless when  he transforms into Garruk, the Veil-Cursed. In most cases, he'll have  one or two loyalty counters on him.

Since it's a natural follow up question about the one ability per turn use of a planeswalker

> You can't activate a loyalty ability of Garruk Relentless and later  that turn after he transforms activate a loyalty ability of Garruk, the  Veil-Cursed.

Comment: I had to hunt around to find a citation so I thought it'd be of interest to others.

Comment: it definitely is - it's implied by the lack of loyalty counter on the transformed version, but it's nice to see a ruling.